# clicking on confirm button closes the swal

Tags: angular, typescript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

hitting the confirm button closes the swal is this an expected behaviour? If so how can I implement the [loading example](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) shown in the examples? my swal code is

```
<swal #saveSwal
title="Are you sure?"
text ="Do you want to save changes"
cancelButtonColor="#d33"
showCancelButton="true"
cancelButtonText="No! Review"
confirmButtonColor="#3085d6"
confirmButtonText='Yes, Save progress'
(confirm)="save()"
[showLoaderOnConfirm]="true"

[focusCancel]="true">
```

is there a way to keep the swal open and show the loading animation untill an async operation is compleeted ?

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this https://sweetalert2.github.io/#ajax-request

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to set the `preConfirm` property along with `showLoaderOnConfirm` to perform an async call and keep the alert open.
Instead of mentioning all the configuration options for sweetalert in the HTML , it's better to create a property in the component class of type `SweetAlertOptions` and then use property binding with the `[options]` @Input decorator provided with the `<swal></swal>` component.

For this you have to import `SweetAlertOptions` like below

```
import swal,{ SweetAlertOptions } from 'sweetalert2';
```

I have also created a button to open the alert manually in component class and used `.then()` to show the success message once the async operation is done.I have used `ViewChild` and imported `SwalComponent` for this.

**Code for component class**

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import swal,{ SweetAlertOptions } from 'sweetalert2';
import { SwalComponent } from '@toverux/ngx-sweetalert2';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 4';

  public alertOption:SweetAlertOptions = {};
  @ViewChild('saveSwal') private saveSwal: SwalComponent;

  constructor(){
    this.alertOption = {
      title:"Are you sure?",
      text:"Do you want to save changes",
      cancelButtonColor:"#d33",
      showCancelButton:true,
      cancelButtonText:"No! Review",
      confirmButtonColor:"#3085d6",
      confirmButtonText:'Yes, Save progress',
      showLoaderOnConfirm:true,
      focusCancel:true,
      preConfirm: () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Doing async operation");
        resolve()
      }, 5000)
    })
  },
  allowOutsideClick: () => !swal.isLoading()
    }
  }

  showAlert(evt:any){
    this.saveSwal.show().then(() => {
      swal({
      type: 'success',
      title: 'Ajax request finished!'
    })
   })
  }
  save(){
    console.log("data saved");
  }
}
```

**HTML file**

app.component.html

```
<swal #saveSwal
(confirm)="save()"
[options]="alertOption"
>
</swal>

<button (click)="showAlert($event)">Click here</button>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { SweetAlert2Module } from '@toverux/ngx-sweetalert2';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, SweetAlert2Module.forRoot()],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

with this code , the alert will remain open with the loader until the async call is done and then the success message will be displayed.

Working demo : 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-ifaa17?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: what if save() by itself is an async operation?

Comment: @MahiTejGvp then you can call save as you are doing now like below `(confirm)="save()"` . The `confirm` event is emitted after the `preconfirm` async operation is done.